# Laravel 5.2 - Use controller store() to insert a new DB record

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have a controller named `HeroController` and I want to create a new hero object and insert it to my database as a new hero.

My controller contains the following method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $hero = new Hero;
        $hero->name = $request->name;
        $hero->description = $request->description;
        $hero->avatar = "None";
        $hero->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

I want to use this method when the user is posting the "Add a new hero" form.
Actually what happens is that i'm creating a new hero via my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::post('/heroes/create', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $hero = new Hero;
    $heroname = $request->name;
    $hero->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

Why my hero is created in ths `routes.php` and how I can change it to work with my HeroController? it feels more right this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward, if I understand correctly:

```
Route::post('/heroes/create', 'HeroController@store');
```

It would be best to go through the controller [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers)

Answer (score 2):

You really need to learn about `RESTful controllers` and resource routes. This is exactly what you want.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

You should use `create` action to return a view with a hero creation form and `store` action to create and save data in DB, based on user input.

So all the logic will be inside a controller and the only route you will have is:

```
Route::resource('heroes', 'HeroController');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Route to
                        Route::post("heroes/create","HeroController@store");

And copy the content of your current route to the store function in your HeroController

Answer (score -1):

```
$data= new Data();
    $data->fill($request->all());
    $data->save();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?